# Multiple websites inside asp .net website

Tags: asp.net, hosting

Hi I am creating an application where user wants to create and upload multiple websites inside asp .net website. 
like 
www.mywebsite.com/Websites/Website1
www.mywebsite.com/Websites/Website2
www.mywebsite.com/Websites/Website3
www.mywebsite.com/Websites/Website4

If I upload static website(No database connectivity) to Website1,Website2,Website3 folder it is working fine but If upload website have database in App_Data folder and connection string in web.config folder it is giving me error like : `It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.`

Does anyone knows how to solve this issue???

Thanks.

Comment: how do you create your directories in runtime for the uploaded sites!

Comment: I am just creating multiple websites using visual studio and uploading those websites to a folder in main website.

Comment: but how do you create them, do you do this manually or write code to do it for you, if so can you tell me what code you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your suggestions and comments... Few more requirements added to project and goal changed... Now How I am doing (Thought it would be helpful for someone else):

1) Now I am using single Master page for my main website and for multiple websites.
2) Now using single web.config for all the websites(main as well as sub-websites). Because as I have mentioned in my question... static websites are working fine but only problem in database driven websites.

I am not sure that this is the best practice(Who cares when you have no choice :p) but .. It has solved my problem

Last but not Least Thanks @Douglas Thomas and @Shirish ... I have tried this convert to application method on my local IIS and it worked perfectly but now as I have accomplished by other way ... I do not need to contact hosting company [ Some times they made me Angry ] every single time I upload new sub website.

Answer (score 2):

For this Just `add virtual directory` and put `web.config` and `aspnet_client` in that folder and then browse virtual directory..

Comment: But I want to add multiple websites... so I have create virtual directory for each website???.... And I am using hosting company to host my website.

Comment: Just ask your hosting provider to configure it for you. Go to IIS--> domain--> directory--> right click and then convert it to application.

Comment: @MaxPayne you can do that as Douglas Thomas told, and also hosting company provide automatic paths so whenever you will add any project in project it will automatic configure as web application and if not convert then you have to contact hosting company and ask for IIS settings..